# Special Administration Console (SAC) in linux

Tags: linux, windows, console, serial

Windows have **Special Administration Console (SAC)**, same feature is available to linux?
Refer http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc785873(v=ws.10).aspx

Comment: Are you really wanting a serial line interface?  Or... what feature of SAC are you wanting?  If you "ssh" (secure shell) into the box (you would need an account on the box -- as you would to login from a serial-line interface).  From there, you'd "su" to root and use any available command to administer the system, if you have "X" running locally, you can also have "X" based utils on the server display on your local display.  I can't see why you would want a serial line -- but if that's what you want, you can hook one up.  You don't need to be on a "console" to admin a linux system.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Windows' Special Administration Console is essentially a backdoor command-line interface to allow you to administrate Windows over a Serial line when you can't remote in over the network for some reason.

Linux allows full access to the system over the serial line, this is usually configured just by adding something along the lines of 'console=ttyS0,115200' to the kernel commandline (this is usually done by editing the configuration of your bootloader, e.g /boot/grub/menu.lst on Debian/Ubuntu or /etc/default/grub on later Ubuntu, Fedora or Redhat systems).

You won't get the esoteric interface provided by the SAC, but you will get full access to the Linux system, and should be able to recover a system with broken networking/boot etc. There's some good documentation on this [here](http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/Remote-Serial-Console-HOWTO/).